# file name contains string in batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I want to rename 2 files and remove only +number from their names. For example I have 2 files, `localhost+3.pem` and `localhost+3-key.pem` and I want to change them to `localhost.pem` and `localhost-key.pem` respectively.

So far I have came up with this script to find pem files in current directory but I don't know how to rename them to desired names.

```
@ECHO OFF
for %%f in (*.pem) do (
  echo %%f
)
PAUSE
```

I don't know, in advance, the number after `+` in the file names

Comment: if it's always a single digit number after the plus sign, then just `rename "localhost+?*.pem" localhost.pem`  and `rename "localhost+?-key.pem" localhost-key.pem`.

Comment: @PA. Thank you can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @PA., I guess you meant the first command line without the `*`, right? Anyway, if there can be more than just a single digit, do: `ren "localhost+*-key.pem" "localhost-key.*"`, and **then** `ren "localhost+*.pem" "localhost.pem"`...

Comment: @aschipfl yes, typo corrected in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's always a single digit number after the plus sign, then just try

```
rename "localhost+?.pem" localhost.pem
rename "localhost+?-key.pem" localhost-key.pem
```